# Recover the value of user in dropdown list

Tags: php

I would like to recover  the value of the click of the user  in a dropdown list.

For example i have this :

```
<form id="form-recipe" action="essaie4.php?IDR=<?php echo($ET2['IDR'])?>" method="POST">


      <label for="ing-select">Ingrédient</label>
      <!--<select id="ing-select" class="ingredients" name="ingId" onChange="header("Location: essaie4.php?$IDR=<?php //echo $_GET['$IDR'];?>">-->
       <input id = "surface" name="ingred" type="TEXT"/> 


      <!--<select id="essaie1" onclick="this.form.ingred.value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">-->
                    <option id= "1"value="1">salade</option>
                    <option id = "2"value="2">steak</option>
                    <option id = "3"value="3">pain</option>
                    <option value="4">oignons</option>
                    <option value="5">ketchup </option>
                    <option value="10">totame</option>
                    <option value="11">sauceuranium</option>
                    <option value="12">cornichon</option>
               </select>
```

And I would like recover the click of the user,  if he clicks on "salade"  or on "steak"  I recover this value, ( value=1) or value=2 for steak ...  but I don't want use javascript, i want do it in php, but I have no idea how do it.

I don't want use if isset( ) because i would do too much if isset

Thanks for reading me

EDIT :

Thanks but , why when I do :

```
<?php
$query3 = "SELECT id_ingredient from composition where id_recette=$IDR;";
    $response3 = $db->query($query3);
    $response3->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

    //On boucle sur toutes les lignes récupérées
    foreach ($response3 as $row) {
        //On crée un tableau qui contiendra toutes nos personnes
        $persons3[] = $row;
    }
    $response3->closeCursor();
?>


if (!empty($_POST["ingred"]) AND (!empty($_POST["quanti"]))){
$var_ingred = $_POST["ingred"];
$var_quanti = $_POST['quanti'];
foreach($persons3 as $ET3){
    #echo ($ET3['id_ingredient']);
    #echo $_POST["ingred"];
    if(($ET3['id_ingredient']) ==  $_POST['ingred']      ){//"echo <script>e</script>"){
    $condition = 1;}
    else{
    $condition = 0;}
```

If I click on oignons, it already exists in my database,  but why PHP says me that my condition is = 0 and not 1 ?? it always take me the last element who is present ?

i don't unterstand

Comment: Why is the `<select>` commented out? You can't have `<option>` without `<select>`

Answer (score 1):

Put `name="ingred"` in the `<select>`, rather than using a separate text input.

```
<form id="form-recipe" action="essaie4.php?IDR=<?php echo($ET2['IDR'])?>" method="POST">


  <label for="ing-select">Ingrédient</label>

  <select id="ing-select" name="ingred">
    <option id="1" value="1">salade</option>
    <option id="2" value="2">steak</option>
    <option id="3" value="3">pain</option>
    <option value="4">oignons</option>
    <option value="5">ketchup </option>
    <option value="10">totame</option>
    <option value="11">sauceuranium</option>
    <option value="12">cornichon</option>
  </select>
```

Then you get the selection using `$_POST['ingred']` in PHP after the form is submitted.

Comment: The problem is that  I don't recover the value ofthe click

Comment: For example ,  if the users click on oignons,  how I have the value oignons ?

Comment: When the user submits the form, `$_POST['ingred']` will be `4`.

Comment: Thanks I Add answer for my problem with this solution in new answer

Answer (score 0):

PHP can only handle this functionality if your `#form-recipe` form is *submited* (clicking **submit** button).

Give the `select` element a `name` attribute:

```html
<form id="form-recipe" action="/some/action" method="POST">
    <select name="foo">
        <option value='1'>salade</option>
        <option value='2'>steak</option>
        <!-- Etc... -->
    </select>
</form>
```

When the user submits the form, `$_POST['foo']` will hold the value of the selection option. *1* for *salade*, *2* for *steak*, etc...